# using host-context to select child classes

Tags: html, css, angular

How can I use `host-context` so that I can theme `child classes` accordingly?

```
<app-root _nghost-fyd-c0="" ng-version="8.2.14" class="desktop-theme">
   <div _ngcontent-fyd-c0="" class="container">
      <app-header _ngcontent-fyd-c0="" _nghost-fyd-c1="">
         <p _ngcontent-fyd-c1="">header works!</p>
      </app-header>
      <div _ngcontent-fyd-c0="" class="app-home">
         <p _ngcontent-fyd-c0="">This is body content</p>
      </div>
      <app-footer _ngcontent-fyd-c0="" _nghost-fyd-c2="">
         <p _ngcontent-fyd-c2="">footer works!</p>
      </app-footer>
   </div>
</app-root>
```

I am want to use something like this. When the resolution changes, the app-root class different theme applied dynamically, so that I can choose the theme accordingly and apply inner styles.

The below is not working.

```
.desktop-theme .app-home {
   apply styles here
}

:host-context(.desktop-theme) .app-home {
   apply styles here
}
```